# Deadlock caused by SELECT JOIN statement with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, join, sql-server-2000, deadlock

When executing a SELECT statement with a JOIN of two tables SQL Server seems to
lock both tables of the statement individually. For example by a query like
this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.id = table2.id
    WHERE ...
```

I found out that the order of the locks depends on the WHERE condition. The
query optimizer tries to produce an execution plan that only reads as much
rows as necessary. So if the WHERE condition contains a column of table1
it will first get the result rows from table1 and then get the corresponding
rows from table2. If the column is from table2 it will do it the other way
round. More complex conditions or the use of indexes may have an effect on
the decision of the query optimizer too.

When the data read by a statement should be updated later in the transaction
with UPDATE statements it is not guaranteed that the order of the UPDATE
statements matches the order that was used to read the data from the 2 tables.
If another transaction tries to read data while a transaction is updating the
tables it can cause a deadlock when the SELECT statement is executed in
between the UPDATE statements because neither the SELECT can get the lock on
the first table nor can the UPDATE get the lock on the second table. For
example:

```
T1: SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ...
T1: UPDATE table1 SET ... WHERE id = ?
T2: SELECT ... FROM ... JOIN ... (locks table2, then blocked by lock on table1)
T1: UPDATE table2 SET ... WHERE id = ?
```

Both tables represent a type hierarchy and are always loaded together. So it
makes sense to load an object using a SELECT with a JOIN. Loading both tables
individually would not give the query optimizer a chance to find the best
execution plan. But since UPDATE statements can only update one table at a
time this can causes deadlocks when an object is loaded while the object
is updated by another transaction. Updates of objects often cause UPDATEs on
both tables when properties of the object that belong to different types of the
type hierarchy are updated.

I have tried to add locking hints to the SELECT statement, but that does not
change the problem. It just causes the deadlock in the SELECT statements when
both statements try to lock the tables and one SELECT statement gets the lock
in the opposite order of the other statement. Maybe it would be possible to
load data for updates always with the same statement forcing the locks to be
in the same order. That would prevent a deadlock between two transactions that
want to update the data, but would not prevent a transaction that only reads
data to deadlock which needs to have different WHERE conditions.

The only work-a-round so this so far seems to be that reads may not get locks
at all. With SQL Server 2005 this can be done using SNAPSHOT ISOLATION. The
only way for SQL Server 2000 would be to use the READ UNCOMMITED isolation
level.

I would like to know if there is another possibilty to prevent the SQL Server
from causing these deadlocks?

Comment: If that is a question the answer is no. It happens with all isolation levels, except maybe READ UNCOMMITTED that i did not test, because I don't want that transactions can read half updated data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will never happen under snapshot isolation, when readers do not block writers. Other than that, there is no way to prevent such things. I wrote a lot of repro scripts here: [Reproducing deadlocks involving only one table](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/01/reproducing-deadlocks-involving-only-one-table.aspx)

Edit:

I don't have access to SQL 2000, but I would try to serialize access to the object by using sp_getapplock, so that reading and modifications never run concurrently. If you cannot use sp_getapplock, roll out your own mutex.

Comment: The answer helped me to find a solition with SQL Server 2005 or newer. But the software is still used with SQL Server 2000 too, I can probably implement different solutions for both versions, so a solution that works for all versions or a different solution for SQL Server 2000 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to split the select... from... join into multiple select statements. Set the isolation level to read committed. Use table variable to pipe data from select to be joined to other. Use distinct to filter down inserts into these table variables.

So if I've two tables A, B. I'm inserting/updating into A and then B. Where as the sql's query optimizer prefers to read B first and A. I'll split the single select into 2 selects. First I'll read B. Then pass on this data to next select statement which reads A.

Here deadlock won't happen because the read locks on table B will be released as soon as 1st statement is done.

PS I've faced this issue and this worked very good. Much better than my force order answer.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue. Using query hint FORCE ORDER will fix this issue. The downside is you won't be able to leverage best plan that query optimizer has for your query, but this will prevent the deadlock.

So (this is from "Bill the Lizard" user) if you have a query FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 and your WHERE clause only contains columns from table2 the execution plan will normally first select the rows from table2 and then look up the rows from table1. With a small result set from table2 only a few rows from table1 have to be fetched. With FORCE ORDER first all rows from table1 have to be fetched, because it has no WHERE clause, then the rows from table2 are joined and the result is filtered using the WHERE clause. Thus degrading performance.

But if you know this won't be the case, use this. You might want to optimize the query manually.

The syntax is

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
        ON table1.id = table2.id
    WHERE ...
OPTION (FORCE ORDER)
```

Comment: Actually I wrote the comment about the performance, seems Stack Overflow has messed up your answer and my comment, i already wondered why it disappeared. The problem is not only the performance with FORCE ORDER, it is also the locking. If you use FORCE ORDER and it causes the execution plan to read all rows from table1, it also puts a shared lock on them. So basically every query that is only using columns from table2, will lock the whole table1 making any updates impossible. It is not a single query that needs to work, the SELECT has to work with any WHERE clause.

Comment: So you don't want to lock table1, while be able to join with table2? In my case, I had inserts happening in table1 and then in table2. And query optimizer was picking reverse order in case of join. So deadlock. Adding FORCE ORDER resolved that hence no deadlock. Note here I do still want read lock on table1. Inserts can wait till the select finishes. But there won't be any deadlock.

Comment: No locks are ok on table1, but with FORCE ORDER it locks all rows in the table instead of only the rows that need to be joined with the rows from table2. Allocating locks for all rows can also become a problem, because it is a resource processes have to allocate. If the SQL Server runs our of memory for locks, processes can deadlocks on memory allocation.