# Is it possible for two processes to create a deadlock in SQL Server without either process modifying a table?

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I am trying to simulate a deadlock condition in SQL Server. I have found a number of StackExchange posts about how to simulate a deadlock condition by using an UPDATE or INSERT statement, but I'd like to be able to simulate the deadlock without modifying the table.
Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712827/deadlock-caused-by-select-join-statement-with-sql-server

Comment: https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/options-for-fixing-parallel-deadlocks/

Comment: _"but I'd like to be able to simulate the deadlock without modifying the table"_ - **why?**

Comment: Yes, it totally is possible. Deadlocks aren't about modifying data, they're about two (or more) processes waiting for locks that will never yield. e.g.: with two SSMS tabs open you can cause deadlocks by selecting the same single rows from tableA and tableB in one window and tableB and tableA in the other, simply by using `with (xlock)` hints or any variant and a `waitfor delay` in between. (Inside transactions, obviously.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Methinks you should post that as an answer (can you include a screenrecording GIF of you deadlocking in SSMS too? :D )

Comment: @Dai no GIFs for U. :)

Answer (score 2):

Deadlocks aren't about modifying data, they're about two (or more) processes waiting for locks that will never yield.

In SQL Server the database engine has a lock monitor that (by default) executes every five seconds looking for deadlocking processes and chooses the least expensive one to rollback, ref: [Transaction locking and row versioning guide # Deadlock detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#deadlock_detection).

It is possible to create a deadlock scenario with `select` statements just by causing two SPIDs to select from opposing tables with appropriate locks whilst running inside transactions. Knowing that the lock monitor is invoked every five seconds we specify a ten second delay between our table selects in each tab.

Consider the following setup code:

```sql
create table dbo.TableA (
    AID int not null
);
insert dbo.TableA (AID) values ( (1) );

create table dbo.TableB (
    BID int not null
);
insert dbo.TableB (BID) values ( (1) );
```

In our first tab we execute the following code:

```sql
begin tran;
select * from dbo.TableA with (xlock) where AID = 1;
waitfor delay '00:00:10.000';
select * from dbo.TableB with (xlock) where BID = 1;
rollback tran;
```

In our second tab we execute the following code, selecting from the opposite tables:

```sql
begin tran;
select * from dbo.TableB with (xlock) where BID = 1;
waitfor delay '00:00:10.000';
select * from dbo.TableA with (xlock) where AID = 1;
rollback tran;
```

One of the tabs will complete both selects successfully, the other will return an error message such as the following:

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 45, Line 4
Transaction (Process ID 58) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Comment: Why does this need to be done through a transaction in order to simulate the deadlock?

Comment: The user-created transactions control the lifetime of the locks. If you don't wrap the statements in user-created transactions then the locks will only last for the duration of the implicit transactions on each statement, so you cannot generate a deadlock scenario (with `select`s). You can still cause deadlock scenarios inside implicit transactions, but that requires the use of DML statements, and your question was how to cause deadlocks without DML statements.